# How are linear combination of energy eigenstates solutions to the TISE?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, superposition, time-evolution

My textbook states that:

> TISE is a generic eigenvalue problem and the superposition state is not a solution to the TISE.

Another part of textbook (in context of infinite square well):

> The most general solutions will be linear combination of these energy eigenstates with their associated time-dependence:
>
> [image]

We have derive the $u_n(x)$ using the TISE using:

> [image: Blockquote]

So i was wondering how the statement is correct when the the linear combination of energy eigenstates are superposition states

> We can write the time evaluation of any quantum state using the energy eigenfunctions

Comment: Hint: In the second part your textbook is talking about the TDSE.

Comment: Please define each acronym the first time it is used. "TISE" is not a standard acronym.